# ChromaDB get list of unique metadata field

Tags: python, chromadb

I'm working with a ChromaDB collection and need to efficiently extract a list of all unique values for a specific metadata field.

```
collection = client.get_collection(collection_name)
unique_keys = collection.get(where={"$distinct": "metadata_key"}) #not working as expected

#in db `metadata_key` is like `sentiment` that can have value like good, bad, etc
```

currently I using this **inefficient way**

```
all_metadatas  = collection.get(include=["metadatas"]).get('metadatas')
distinct_keys = set([x.get('metadata_key') for x  in all_metadatas])
```